# SQL Server Drop NULLS in pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a base table. [Base table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBzkB.png) 
I want to put in linear form that is why I use pivot to have it. And my query goes like:

```
select
[report_date] AS 'Date'
,[30],[percent_30] AS '%30'
,[45],[percent_45] AS '%45'
,[60],[percent_60] AS '%60'
,[75],[percent_75] AS '%75'
,[90],[percent_90] AS '%90'
,[105],[percent_105] AS '%105'
,[120],[percent_120] AS '%120'
,[TOTAL] AS 'Total Sales'
--,[total_percentage] AS 'Total Percent'
 from database.dbo.delivery_report_logs  
PIVOT(SUM(Sale_Count) 
      FOR description IN ([30],[45],[60],[75],[90],[105],[120],[TOTAL])) AS pvz
```

But the result looks like this.

I want to remove all nulls. Any help? Thank you.

Here is my expected output:
[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y1m3.png)

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "remove all nulls" please.

Comment: I dont know why you use pivot but you can `GROUP BY report_date` and use `MIN/MAX`

Comment: I want to drop all nulls and display all columns with values. For date 20161024 it should be in one line all data is inlined to that date.

Comment: For questions like these, it always helps to add `Expected Output` to your question. That helps narrow things down for people wanting to help you. Read more about this advise here: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). GL!

Comment: @TT i already updated the question please refer to expected output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
[report_date] AS 'Date'
,[30],[percent_30] AS '%30'
,[45],[percent_45] AS '%45'
,[60],[percent_60] AS '%60'
,[75],[percent_75] AS '%75'
,[90],[percent_90] AS '%90'
,[105],[percent_105] AS '%105'
,[120],[percent_120] AS '%120'
,[TOTAL] AS 'Total Sales'
--,[total_percentage] AS 'Total Percent'
 from database.dbo.delivery_report_logs  
PIVOT ISNULL(SUM(Sale_Count),0) 
      FOR description IN ([30],[45],[60],[75],[90],[105],[120],[TOTAL])) AS pvz
```

Comment: Hi it has an error. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 115
Incorrect syntax near 'ISNULL'.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. I use temporary table to pivot the data and insert it to a log table and it gives me the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a query like this that uses and aggregate with a case expression

```
SELECT  report_date,

        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '30' THEN sale_count END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '30' THEN percent_30 END) AS [percent_30],

        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '45' THEN sale_count END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '45' THEN percent_45 END) AS [percent_45],

        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '60' THEN sale_count END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '60' THEN percent_60 END) AS [percent_60],

        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '75' THEN sale_count END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '75' THEN percent_70 END) AS [percent_70],

        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '90' THEN sale_count END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '90' THEN percent_90 END) AS [percent_90],

        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '105' THEN sale_count END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '105' THEN percent_105 END) AS [percent_105],

        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '120' THEN sale_count END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = '120' THEN percent_120 END) AS [percent_120],

        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = 'TOTAL' THEN sale_count END) AS [30],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Description = 'TOTAL' THEN total_percentage END) AS [total_percentage]

FROM    database.dbo.delivery_report_logs

GROUP BY report_date
```

you can also use MAX or MIN in place of SUM if there is only one value per report_date/percentate